# Can I skip until I reach a certain line when iterating through text in RStudio?

Tags: r, line, skip, txt

I am reading text data using the `read.delim()` -&- `read.delim2()` methods. They accept a skip argument, but it works with number of lines, (i.e. it skips 2,3,4,100 the line you pass into it).

I am using the methods...

##### `read.delim()`

##### `read.delim2()`

...to read text data. The methods above are able to *skip* lines, consequently; the methods have a *skip parameter*, and the parameter accepts an array of line-numbers as an argument. All *line-numbers*  passed into the *skip-parameter* are skipped by the *reader methods* (i.e. the lines are not read by the *reader methods*).

I want to iterate through a body of text, skipping every line until I get to a specific line. Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that in base R functions, and I don't know of a package that *directly* provides that. However, here are two ways to get the effect.

First, a file named `file.txt`:

```
I want to skip this
and this too
Absolute Irradiance
I need this line
```

```r
txt <- readLines("file.txt")
txt[cumany(grepl("Absolute Irradiance", txt))]
# [1] "Absolute Irradiance" "I need this line"
```

If you don't want the "Irradiance" line but want everything after it, then add `[-1]` to remove the first of the returned lines:

```r
txt[cumany(grepl("Absolute Irradiance", txt))][-1]
# [1] "I need this line"
```

If the file is relatively large and you do not want to read all of it into R, then

```r
system2("sed", c("-ne", "'/Absolute Irradiance/,$p'", "file.txt"), stdout = TRUE)
# [1] "Absolute Irradiance" "I need this line"
```

This second technique is really not that great ... it might be better to run that from `file.txt` into a second (temp) file, then just `readLines("tempfile.txt")` directly.

Comment: Both of them work, thanks! 

Can you explain me the second one?

Comment: I can't really explain in detail the `sed` command-line utility in something as small as a "tweet", to be honest. It's a very powerful, decades-old tool that does what it does *very well* and *fast*. It's available on every linux (and likely macos) distro, and it is included within Rtools, so it should be available to most R users. You can see https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sed-command-in-linux-unix-with-examples/ and https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html if you'd like, though it is admittedly not something easily mastered in a day :-)